# Linking Python to pip location [Windows]

Tags: python, pip

When I type pip into my terminal, I get this path:

```
Usage: 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]
```

However, I would like to change it to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`. I saw the Mac and Linux way of doing it, but I don't have either OS at the moment, so I need a windows solution.

Thanks!

Comment: those are two different pythons. Then long one is from the windows store. the other python should have it's own pip, don't try to link them

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a Python package and command line interface that you download with every new version of Python.
Each Python installed on your PC has its own package management/package installer for that particular python.exe. Python is already linked with its own pip.

You can find the pip package folder at:
*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages*

You can find the pip.exe at:
*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts*

If you use `pip` in cmd with the full path to a specific Python, you can manage packages for that Python.

```sh
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]
```

If you want to configure a specific Python for use with the short command "python"/"pip" in the terminal, you can familiarize yourself with
the specifics of [installing and using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).
Notice the Python Launcher for Windows and the addition of Python to your PATH environment variable.

You can check which of the Pythons you installed are added to the PATH variable (in terminal). The first one in the list is started by default when using the short command `python`.

```
where python
```

Same for `pip`:

```
where pip
```

You may need to update your [PATH environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).
Add paths *C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts*,
*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39* to it.

Also check your [App Execution Aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-store).